# Adobe Illustrator not printing layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, layers

I have created a plat map for my job. Problem is, I have multiple layers for advertisements, a map, my rulers, & borders.
I have been trying to print this map for 2 days & it will NOT print any layers besides my advertisment layer.
I have tried to change every print setting I possibly can & have been trying to scour the internet looking for a solution.
So what I am getting is a sheet full of ads from businesses, but nothing else that I have put on this map.
Im going crazy, please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make certain layers are not designated as "Template" layers or non-printing layers in the Layer options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons could be these:

Have you already attempted to click on the layer and open 'layer options' and checked to see if the 'print' box is checked?

Have you checked the file to ensure you have no overprints turned on on that artwork that is not showing up? this should be under the 'Appearance' window, but you may need to check each element individually, as it will only showcase the items that have had it selected, not necessarily a group of items. A quick glance that may help is to turn on and off the view option 'overprint preview'. If the image changes slightly (darkens/lightens in parts) this is the likely cause.

Comment: I have done both of those. I also saved as a pdf & tried to print through adobe reader, but I get the same thing. is it maybe because ive sent some links or strokes to the back or to the front? I really think that is my problem, but I cannot fix it. Ive even tried to redo the whole thing on a fresh page, & it still wouldnt print my border layer. i cant do my job if I cant get this printed right

Comment: I'm sure you don't want to provide a messy file to a client, but to simply get past a printing issue,  you could try saving it as a new file, and put everything you want to print within the one 'working' layer. It could be corrupt in some way, or a simple fix that you haven't thought of yet but this may be a workaround for the time being

Comment: i will try to group everything into one layer & see if that works for me. thank you for your help!

Comment: nope, that did not help

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the elements that do not want to print? it is tricky to troubleshoot without the actual file open. When you go to print, another possibility would be to ensure that in the print dialogue under 'General Options' the dropdown is set to print 'All layers'. Under 'Advanced' select 'simulate' for overprints in case that is the issue

Comment: I want to print all of the elements on my page. I can only get some of the links ive tossed on there to print. nothing else

Comment: sorry @ADesigner I am very very new to illustrator & I really only know the basics. I'm pretty sure its just my printer, but Im scared to change the printer settings haha

Comment: don't worry about that, those settings are meant to be changed! you can click the 'print preset' at the top to go back to 'default' at any time.

Comment: I read somewhere that my problem could be because I cant select the "Print as Bitmap" option. but its grayed out & wont let me check it. do you know how i could change that?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used that function, mine is grayed out as well. Do you have a large amount of complex vector art in your file?

Comment: i wish i knew how to send you a screenshot of my page. i have alot im trying to print on this page. i have a county road map, borders, ads from various businesses, a thing called "small tracts" & a few other ads from my place of employment. it prints only the ads from various businesses

Comment: the largest piece on my page would be the county map, but it wont print that either. i did try to print it on our large canon printer that we use for larger prints like a 36x36 inch. it printed everything on that printer, but not my HP printer

Comment: If one printer managed to print it but another did not, that would lend me to believe it is a problem with the file being too complex for the printer to manage. If that was the problem saving the complex elements as a JPG or other 'raster' style of image and linking to them could fix it...

Comment: ... but since you said it also will not save as a PDF It does not seem to be the case. If the file is complex enough it could cause PDF issues too though, and a workaround to getting a PDF file from something very complicated is to 'print' it as a 'postscript' file first (select postscript from your printer dropdown), which you then open with acrobat distiller if you have the program and save the distiller file as a PDF, which from there you may be able to print it

Comment: i dont have acrobat distller.i did just try to redo my page on a fresh new page & i think i may have figured my problem out. I believe its when i try to send different layers to the front or back. its like it almost hides my border layer. im hoping ive fixed my problem. thank you so much @ADesigner for your help. have a great weekend & i hope 2018 treats you good!

Comment: Hope that solves the problem @hailey!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem... Check each individual elements opacity! 
(Make sure you're looking at the Appearance window.)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please add an screenshot of that "Appearance Windows"?